# Does anyone know of a spell check library that underlines text?

Tags: c#, .net

Does anyone know of a C# spell check library that would underline misspelled works in a windows form text box?  In the past, I've used [NetSpell](http://sourceforge.net/projects/netspell/) and works great if users use the dialog box.

I'm thinking I might be able to automatically call the spell check while text is being updated and underline the text.  Anyone have any good ideas on what would be the best way to go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using **Infragistics**' components.
They offer [WinSpellChecker](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/winspellchecker.aspx) which seems doing the job you are looking for

There is also **[NHunspell](http://nhunspell.sourceforge.net/)** - free open source spell checker what might be used to easily develop control you are talking about

Comment: `"Spell Checker, Hypenation and Thesaurus: NHunspell"` NHunspell must not work very well, unless 'hypenation' crept into their dictionary somehow.

Comment: That is the price you are paying for freeware software :) 
BTW I've made quick look at it and tested spelling and seems works well
But as I said - for our soft  we are using commercial Infragistics components

Comment: I'm really impressed with the WinSpellCheker library.  I'm surprised they are able to underline text in a text box.  I'm wondering if they are just drawing on the control based on the location of the text.  Does anyone know how to get the x, y location of text within a text box?

Answer (score 0):

[DevExpress XtraSpellChecker](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Spell_Checker/) should do the trick.